# A coredump problem occurs when two video streams enter videomixer(Gstreamer)

Tags: c, gstreamer

This is my pipeline

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri="rtsp://169.254.3.48/axis-media/media.amp?camera=1" ! videoconvert ! videomixer name=mixer sink_0::alpha=1 sink_0::xpos=0 sink_1::alpha=1 sink_1::xpos=1280 sink_1::ypos=720     uridecodebin uri="rtsp://169.254.3.48/axis-media/media.amp?camera=2" ! videoconvert ! mixer.sink_1     mixer. ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

I have tested, it can run, but I want to relize it with C，but i meet the problem coredump, This is my information log:

```
0:00:00.000059980 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_INIT gst.c:592:init_pre: Initializing GStreamer Core Library version 1.20.3
0:00:00.000091859 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_INIT gst.c:593:init_pre: Using library installed in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
0:00:00.000114765 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_INIT gst.c:611:init_pre: Linux esigelec-HP-ZBook-15 5.19.0-38-generic #39~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Mar 17 21:16:15 UTC 2 x86_64
0:00:00.000284464 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_INIT gstmessage.c:129:_priv_gst_message_initialize: init messages
0:00:00.000591495 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_INIT gstcontext.c:86:_priv_gst_context_initialize: init contexts
0:00:00.000740848 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:324:_priv_gst_plugin_initialize: registering 0 static plugins
0:00:00.000810831 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:232:gst_plugin_register_static: registered static plugin "staticelements"
0:00:00.000820356 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:234:gst_plugin_register_static: added static plugin "staticelements", result: 1
0:00:00.000872546 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO            GST_REGISTRY gstregistry.c:1827:ensure_current_registry: reading registry cache: /home/esigelec/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/registry.x86_64.bin
0:00:00.010488934 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO            GST_REGISTRY gstregistrybinary.c:683:priv_gst_registry_binary_read_cache: loaded /home/esigelec/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/registry.x86_64.bin in 0.009593 seconds
0:00:00.010567873 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO            GST_REGISTRY gstregistry.c:1693:scan_and_update_registry: Validating plugins from registry cache: /home/esigelec/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/registry.x86_64.bin
0:00:00.011603153 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO            GST_REGISTRY gstregistry.c:1785:scan_and_update_registry: Registry cache has not changed
0:00:00.011613613 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO            GST_REGISTRY gstregistry.c:1862:ensure_current_registry: registry reading and updating done, result = 1
0:00:00.011632624 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_INIT gst.c:833:init_post: GLib runtime version: 2.72.4
0:00:00.011641836 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_INIT gst.c:835:init_post: GLib headers version: 2.72.1
0:00:00.011648242 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_INIT gst.c:837:init_post: initialized GStreamer successfully
0:00:00.012858795 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:987:_priv_gst_plugin_load_file_for_registry: plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstplayback.so" loaded
0:00:00.012950518 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:489:gst_element_factory_create_with_properties: creating element "uridecodebin"
0:00:00.012985878 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:489:gst_element_factory_create_with_properties: creating element "uridecodebin"
0:00:00.013149535 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:987:_priv_gst_plugin_load_file_for_registry: plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideoconvert.so" loaded
0:00:00.013313689 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:489:gst_element_factory_create_with_properties: creating element "videoconvert"
0:00:00.013347360 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:759:gst_element_add_pad:<GstBaseTransform@0x55aa0d6a5420> adding pad 'sink'
0:00:00.013361093 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:759:gst_element_add_pad:<GstBaseTransform@0x55aa0d6a5420> adding pad 'src'
0:00:00.013371859 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:489:gst_element_factory_create_with_properties: creating element "videoconvert"
0:00:00.013386086 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:759:gst_element_add_pad:<GstBaseTransform@0x55aa0d6a80d0> adding pad 'sink'
0:00:00.013397258 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:759:gst_element_add_pad:<GstBaseTransform@0x55aa0d6a80d0> adding pad 'src'
0:00:00.013574299 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:987:_priv_gst_plugin_load_file_for_registry: plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideomixer.so" loaded
0:00:00.013656047 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO              videomixer videomixer2.c:2187:gst_videomixer2_child_proxy_init: initializing child proxy interface
0:00:00.013669737 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:489:gst_element_factory_create_with_properties: creating element "videomixer"
0:00:00.013942915 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:759:gst_element_add_pad:<GstVideoMixer2@0x55aa0d6ac120> adding pad 'src'
0:00:00.014396309 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:987:_priv_gst_plugin_load_file_for_registry: plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstcoreelements.so" loaded
0:00:00.014457444 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:489:gst_element_factory_create_with_properties: creating element "queue"
0:00:00.014502852 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:759:gst_element_add_pad:<GstQueue@0x55aa0d6b4070> adding pad 'sink'
0:00:00.014518167 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:759:gst_element_add_pad:<GstQueue@0x55aa0d6b4070> adding pad 'src'
0:00:00.014660526 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:987:_priv_gst_plugin_load_file_for_registry: plugin "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstautodetect.so" loaded
0:00:00.014702119 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:489:gst_element_factory_create_with_properties: creating element "autovideosink"
0:00:00.014743564 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:759:gst_element_add_pad:<sinkvideo> adding pad 'sink'
0:00:00.014814926 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:489:gst_element_factory_create_with_properties: creating element "fakesink"
0:00:00.014831996 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:759:gst_element_add_pad:<GstBaseSink@0x55aa0d6bee90> adding pad 'sink'
0:00:00.014862427 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:1016:gst_element_get_static_pad: found pad fake-video-sink:sink
0:00:00.014872864 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2382:gst_pad_link_prepare: trying to link sink:proxypad0 and fake-video-sink:sink
0:00:00.014892020 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2590:gst_pad_link_full: linked sink:proxypad0 and fake-video-sink:sink, successful
0:00:00.014907493 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO               GST_EVENT gstevent.c:1660:gst_event_new_reconfigure: creating reconfigure event
0:00:00.014923281 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:489:gst_element_factory_create_with_properties: creating element "pipeline"
0:00:00.014989159 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1816:gst_element_link_pads_full: trying to link element mixer:(any) to element queue1:(any)
0:00:00.015004285 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_PADS gstutils.c:1079:gst_pad_check_link: trying to link mixer:src and queue1:sink
0:00:00.015019691 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:4357:gst_pad_peer_query:<queue1:src> pad has no peer
0:00:00.015030622 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_PADS gstutils.c:1632:prepare_link_maybe_ghosting: mixer and queue1 in same bin, no need for ghost pads
0:00:00.015042353 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2382:gst_pad_link_prepare: trying to link mixer:src and queue1:sink
0:00:00.015051525 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:4357:gst_pad_peer_query:<queue1:src> pad has no peer
0:00:00.015060397 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2590:gst_pad_link_full: linked mixer:src and queue1:sink, successful
0:00:00.015065568 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO               GST_EVENT gstevent.c:1660:gst_event_new_reconfigure: creating reconfigure event
0:00:00.015073289 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO               GST_EVENT gstpad.c:5946:gst_pad_send_event_unchecked:<mixer:src> Received event on flushing pad. Discarding
0:00:00.015085627 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1816:gst_element_link_pads_full: trying to link element queue1:(any) to element sinkvideo:(any)
0:00:00.015093916 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_PADS gstutils.c:1079:gst_pad_check_link: trying to link queue1:src and sinkvideo:sink
0:00:00.015107892 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_PADS gstutils.c:1632:prepare_link_maybe_ghosting: queue1 and sinkvideo in same bin, no need for ghost pads
0:00:00.015117020 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2382:gst_pad_link_prepare: trying to link queue1:src and sinkvideo:sink
0:00:00.015131099 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2590:gst_pad_link_full: linked queue1:src and sinkvideo:sink, successful
0:00:00.015139450 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO               GST_EVENT gstevent.c:1660:gst_event_new_reconfigure: creating reconfigure event
0:00:00.015150345 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO               GST_EVENT gstpad.c:5946:gst_pad_send_event_unchecked:<queue1:src> Received event on flushing pad. Discarding
0:00:00.015165519 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:1013:gst_element_get_static_pad: no such pad 'sink_0' in element "mixer"
0:00:00.015193037 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:759:gst_element_add_pad:<mixer> adding pad 'sink_0'
0:00:00.015201518 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:1016:gst_element_get_static_pad: found pad convertvideo0:src
0:00:00.015209304 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2382:gst_pad_link_prepare: trying to link convertvideo0:src and mixer:sink_0
0:00:00.015216131 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:4357:gst_pad_peer_query:<convertvideo0:sink> pad has no peer
0:00:00.015396213 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2590:gst_pad_link_full: linked convertvideo0:src and mixer:sink_0, successful
0:00:00.015404435 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO               GST_EVENT gstevent.c:1660:gst_event_new_reconfigure: creating reconfigure event
0:00:00.015410946 2056458 0x55aa0d40f400 INFO               GST_EVENT gstpad.c:5946:gst_pad_send_event_unchecked:<convertvideo0:src> Received event on flushing pad. Discarding
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

My two funtion for Callback to connect `uridecodebin` and `videoconvert`, because I have two `uridecodebin`, so I create 2 functions for Callback, this is my deux function code:

```c
static void
    pad_added_handler (GstElement * src, GstPad * new_pad, CustomData * data)
   {
     //GstPad *sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad (data->convert, "sink");
      GstPad *Sink_pad_video = gst_element_get_static_pad (data->convertVideo, "sink");
     //GstPad *Sink_pad_video_1 = gst_element_get_static_pad (data->convertVideo1, "sink");

      GstPadLinkReturn ret;
      GstCaps *new_pad_caps = NULL;
      GstStructure *new_pad_struct = NULL;
      const gchar *new_pad_type = NULL;


      g_print ("Received new pad '%s' from '%s':\n", GST_PAD_NAME (new_pad),
       GST_ELEMENT_NAME (src));


  /* If our converter is already linked, we have nothing to do here */
      if (gst_pad_is_linked (Sink_pad_video)) {
        g_print ("We are already linked. Ignoring.\n");
        goto exit;
  }

 
  /* Check the new pad's type */
  new_pad_caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps (new_pad);
  new_pad_struct = gst_caps_get_structure (new_pad_caps, 0);
  new_pad_type = gst_structure_get_name (new_pad_struct);
  if (!g_str_has_prefix (new_pad_type, "audio/x-raw")) {
    g_print ("It has type '%s' which is raw video.\n",
        new_pad_type);
    //goto exit;
    ret = gst_pad_link (new_pad, Sink_pad_video);
  } //else {
    //ret = gst_pad_link (new_pad, sink_pad);
  //}


  if (GST_PAD_LINK_FAILED (ret)) {
    g_print ("Type is '%s' but link failed.\n", new_pad_type);
  } else {
    g_print ("Link succeeded source0 (type '%s').\n", new_pad_type);
  }


exit:
  /* Unreference the new pad's caps, if we got them */
  if (new_pad_caps != NULL)
    gst_caps_unref (new_pad_caps);
 

  /* Unreference the sink pad */
  //gst_object_unref (sink_pad);
  gst_object_unref (Sink_pad_video);
}
 

/*pour uridecoder1*/
static void
pad_added_handler_1 (GstElement * src, GstPad * new_pad, CustomData * data)
{
  GstPad *Sink_pad_video_1 = gst_element_get_static_pad (data->convertVideo1, "sink");

  GstPadLinkReturn ret;
  GstCaps *new_pad_caps = NULL;
  GstStructure *new_pad_struct = NULL;
  const gchar *new_pad_type = NULL;


  g_print ("Received new pad '%s' from '%s':\n", GST_PAD_NAME (new_pad),
      GST_ELEMENT_NAME (src));


  /* If our converter is already linked, we have nothing to do here */
  if (gst_pad_is_linked (Sink_pad_video_1) ) {
    g_print ("We are already linked. Ignoring.\n");
    goto exit;
  }
 

  /* Check the new pad's type */
  new_pad_caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps (new_pad);
  new_pad_struct = gst_caps_get_structure (new_pad_caps, 0);
  new_pad_type = gst_structure_get_name (new_pad_struct);
  if (!g_str_has_prefix (new_pad_type, "audio/x-raw")) {
    g_print ("It has type '%s' which is raw video.\n",
        new_pad_type);
    //goto exit;
    ret = gst_pad_link (new_pad, Sink_pad_video_1);
  } //else {
    //ret = gst_pad_link (new_pad, sink_pad);
  //}

  if (GST_PAD_LINK_FAILED (ret)) {
    g_print ("Type is '%s' but link failed.\n", new_pad_type);
  } else {
    g_print ("Link succeeded source1 (type '%s').\n", new_pad_type);
  }

exit:
  /* Unreference the new pad's caps, if we got them */
  if (new_pad_caps != NULL)
    gst_caps_unref (new_pad_caps);

  /* Unreference the sink pad */
  //gst_object_unref (sink_pad);
  gst_object_unref (Sink_pad_video_1);
}
```